# MySQL - INSERT INTO from SELECT with passed in value in Node Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to insert a passed in RFID card value, along with its associated data from another table i.e. the user of the card.

I am using the `mysql` npm library.

```
let uid = req.body.uid;

let connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

connection.connect();

const query = `
    INSERT INTO record (uid, userId, user, timestamp) 
        SELECT ?, userId, concat(name, ' ', lastname), NOW() 
        FROM card c 
            LEFT JOIN user u on  u.id = c.userId
        WHERE c.uid = ?
`;

connection.query(query, uid, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: error
        });
    } else {
        console.log(results);
        res.status(200).send({
            message: results
        });
    }
});

connection.end();
```

If I don't put the `WHERE` clause, the code inserts all the available cards, instead of the one read/passed in.

However, the `WHERE` clause gives me an error due to the `?` variable.

I can't wrap my head around how to accomplish the `INSERT` for just the one card. Maybe I don't even need the clause.

Answer (score 0):

I am retarded. This is the working query.

```
INSERT INTO record (uid, userId, user, timestamp) 
    SELECT c.uid, userId, concat(name, ' ', lastname), NOW() 
    FROM card c 
        LEFT JOIN user u on  u.id = c.userId
    WHERE c.uid = ?
```